# Cross tabulation in R

Tags: r, pivot-table

I have a data set consisting of subjects scored by two raters. I would like to obtain a crosstab of cases where rater agreement was found.

```
# Column names
pro <- c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5")

# Rows
R1 <- c("Poor", "Acceptable", "Acceptable", "Good", "Acceptable")
R2 <- c("Poor", "Acceptable", "Good", "Good", "Acceptable")

# Data
data1 <- rbind(R1, R2)
colnames(data1) <- pro
as.data.frame(data1)
```

Desired Result (R1's ratings in the rows, R2's ratings in the columns):

| Poor | Acceptable | Good |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross tabulation there is `xtabs` :

```
xtabs(~R1 + R2)
```

To have the rows and columns order in the question, use

```
levs <- c("Poor", "Acceptable", "Good")
R1 <- factor(R1, levels = levs)
R2 <- factor(R2, levels = levs)
xtabs(~R1 + R2)
```

Answer (score 2):

That seems the job for `table()`

`table(R1,R2)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to require specific order, you can use `factor`s.

```
> lapply(list(R1, R2), factor, levels=c("Poor", "Acceptable", "Good")) |> 
+   do.call(what='table')
            
             Poor Acceptable Good
  Poor          1          0    0
  Acceptable    0          2    1
  Good          0          0    1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(R1)
c("Poor", "Acceptable", "Acceptable", "Good", "Acceptable")
> dput(R2)
c("Poor", "Acceptable", "Good", "Good", "Acceptable")
```

Comment: ``` lapply(list(R1, R2), factor, levels=c("Poor", "Acceptable", "Good")) %>% do.call(what='table') ``` is O.K

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `data1` in the posted question, we can do

```
df <- as.data.frame(data1)
table(as.data.frame(t(df)))
```

which gives

```
> table(as.data.frame(t(df)))
            R2
R1           Acceptable Good Poor
  Acceptable          2    1    0
  Good                0    1    0
  Poor                0    0    1
```